# Deleting obsolete Joomla Menu Types

Tags: joomla

While programming a Joomla extension I experimented with Menu Types, however while editing/deleting/adding types in the default.xml it doesn't delete the previous ones.

So while I only have 1 menu type defined in the default.xml it still shows all the 'old' ones.

How can I delete those?
I've looked in the database but can't find the reference the these menu types.

Default.xml:

```
<metadata>
    <layout title="COM_GCMAILS_MAILING_VIEW_DEFAULT_TITLE">
        <message>COM_GCMAILS_MAILING_VIEW_DEFAULT_DESC</message>
    </layout>
</metadata>
```

But the menu still shows:
[Menu Types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txbW1.png)

Comment: Looks like a good question to post on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it existed ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I was looking for the answer to this today and discovered that the problem is that the xml files for those old menu types still exist.  You need to go into the following directory and delete the xml files:

```
components/my_component/views/my_view
```

Then you will stop seeing those options show up in the component's menu types. Hope this helps some future developer.

Comment: Please post your answer here: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/26236/12352